# Getting Apple T2 Audio to work with JACK

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack, apple

The machine in question is a Macbook Pro 16,2(16 inch, 2019). I'm trying to start JACK server on that so that I could use MIDI and have audio the same time in Ardour.

So far stuffs I have tried:

In Ubuntu and Ubuntu Studio(22.04 LTS), with [t2-ubantu-kernel](https://github.com/t2linux/T2-Ubuntu-Kernel) (which I think provides Apple T2 Audio device or driver):

- start `JACK` with `qjackctl`, with `Apple T2 Audio` as audio interface, various parameters settings: fail with error "ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm"
- start `JACK` with `qjackctl`, with `HDA ATI HDMI` as audio interface, various parameters settings: fail(I'm not sure why, I'll check the output and edit the questions later)
- start `Ardour` with `alsa` as audio system, `Apple T2 Audio` as device: fail with cannot start audio/midi engine
- start `Ardour` with `JACK` as audio system and `HDA ATI HDMI` as device, `alsa_seq` as midi system: successful, no sound, but can see midi signal in midi tracks and sound signal in master
- start `Ardour` with `JACK` as audio system and `Apple T2 Audio` as device, `alsa_seq` as midi system: fail with cannot start audio/midi engine
- start Ardour with `pulseaudio` as audio system and `Apple T2 Audio` as as device, can't select midi system(showing only none as option): successful, have sound, but no midi connection

And here's some observations

- `aplay` and `pulseaudio` work, so alsa knows how to use Apple T2 Audio device, and pulseaudio knows how to use Apple T2 audio through alsa
- starting `fluidsynth` with instructions in [PulseAudioMidi on debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/PulseAudioMidi) works, play on midi keyboard and have sound with no identifiable latency.
- before I switch to t2-kernel, JACK and midi keyboard simply work on Ubuntu Studio(starting from Ardour; just no sound). I think the only available device is dummy.

I want to ask if **anyone ever get Apple T2 Audio to work with JACK** or is there some common workaround to do audio production on Ubuntu(or other distro) on a T2 Mac. If anyone could point out what my problem might be and how to solve them that would be the best.

ps: come to think of it, if alsa works and JACK works on top of alsa, then it should just work, or some configuration of JACK's way of using alsa to copy alsa's normal behaviour like that with aplay or the way pulseaudio did, but there's nothing I can find on the web about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with pipewire, here's what I did:

**1. reinstalled the system**

To create a clean and easy-to-reproduce environment.

1. install Ubuntu Studio
2. do mannual kernel update according to [t2linux](https://wiki.t2linux.org/distributions/debian/installation/)
3. create /etc/grub.d/08_t2support, and copy the first menu item in /boot/grub/grub.cfg into it, changing vmlinuz and initrd to the ones you just downloaded. They could be found under `/boot`, then `sudo update-grub`

`/etc/grub.d/08_t2support` looks like this. The function of it is to add a menuitem in front of everything that would load the kernel you just downloaded.

```
    echo "menuentry 'Ubuntu (t2 support)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-22dd21ec-2569-41c2-84e2-64aba99bada0' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  22dd21ec-2569-41c2-84e2-64aba99bada0
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 22dd21ec-2569-41c2-84e2-64aba99bada0
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.3.9-t2-jammy root=UUID=22dd21ec-2569-41c2-84e2-64aba99bada0 ro  threadirqs quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.3.9-t2-jammy
}"
```

**2.install/enable pipewire**

I followed [this tutorial](https://linux.how2shout.com/enable-pipewire-for-audio-and-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-22-04-or-20-04/)

**3. run pipewire in place of jack**

short version:

check [ubuntu manuals page for pw-jack](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man1/pw-jack.1.html) to find which package `pw-jack` is in, install it, and prefix it with every jack-aware program you want to use(just to be safe)

long version:

this is the tricky part, I read various posts and watched youtube videos about how pipewire and ardour work together, but most don't say, or say they "just worked out-of-box" which is hardly my case. Luckily, I spotted `pw-jack` in [this unfa video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7XrrBXIzfg) which seems to do the work. It is not in standard pipewire package and [pipewire-jack](https://github.com/PipeWire/pipewire-jack) is irrelevent. I searched "pw-jack" in google and found it on [ubuntu manuals page for pw-jack](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man1/pw-jack.1.html), which writes it is provided in pipewire-audio-client-libraries package. I installed it, then `pw-jack qjackctl` shows that jack is active, `pw-jack ardour` add it to a running jack connection, everything appear in qjackctl's graph, and everything works just fine.

Comment: I should note here that after a period of time pw-jack is no longer needed for qjackctl to run or ardour to run with jack as audio system. Nothing has been done by me to the system during the change